# Error in Using Gparted to add Unallocated space

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, live-usb, gparted

I'm trying to Add Unallocated space to my Ubuntu partition which is inside an extended partition. i get this error:

```
GParted 0.12.1 --enable-libparted-dmraid

Libparted 2.3
Move /dev/sda3 to the left and grow it from 93.31 GiB to 219.75 GiB  00:00:00        (     ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sda3  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda3
start: 292,704,254
end: 488,394,751
size: 195,690,498 (93.31 GiB)
move partition to the left and grow it from 93.31 GiB to 219.75 GiB  00:00:00    (     ERROR )

old start: 292,704,254
old end: 488,394,751
old size: 195,690,498 (93.31 GiB)
requested start: 27,545,600
requested end: 488,392,703
requested size: 460,847,104 (219.75 GiB)
libparted messages    ( INFO )

Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.
Can't have overlapping partitions.

========================================
```

[image: This is the screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are moving one partition too far, so it makes an overlap with another one. And, thats not possible. And make sure none of the partitions are mounted while processing this.

Comment: added screen shot , also bigger here http://i45.tinypic.com/dzi9ti.png